# Pre-Populate Product Filter On Product Selection Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

So I used URL hack method to prepopulate the filter criteria for the Product selection Page based on a field on opportunity and here is sample controller for overriden Add Product button . For same i have used below code

```
public with sharing class ProductAddCtrl {

private final Opportunity opp;
public string url{get;set;}
public static final string URLCONSTANT='/p/opp/SelectSearch?addTo=';
public static final string RET_URL='&retURL=%2F';
public static final string PRICEBOOKENTRYCOL0 ='&PricebookEntrycol0=';
public static final string PRICEBOOKENTRYCONSTANTS='&PricebookEntryoper0=e&PricebookEntryfval0=';
public static final string NO_OVERRIDE_CONSTANT='&nooverride=1';

public ProductAddCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    this.opp=(Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
}

public pagereference redirect(){

    Opportunity oppvar=[Select Id,Business_Unit__c from Opportunity where Id=:opp.Id LIMIT 1];
    String url=URLCONSTANT;
    url=url+oppvar.Id+RET_URL;
    url=url+oppvar.Id+PRICEBOOKENTRYCOL0+Label.Product_Business_Unit_Field_Id+PRICEBOOKENTRYCONSTANTS+oppvar.Business_Unit__c+NO_OVERRIDE_CONSTANT;
    pagereference p=new pagereference(url);
    p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;
}

 }
```

This works well but with small glitch

[image]

The clear filter link formed after this URL hack does not clear at the top highlightedalthough it resets at bottom table .Anyone familiar with better approaches without complete Visualforce solution

Comment: Sorry Mohith, i've not got any thoughts on this, nor since this is undocumented could i find anything else to learn on it.

Comment: Thanks Andrew .Appreciate your time here and yes undocumented and i will post here if i solution this but seems like hard unless i include some script in home page .anyways thanks lot for all your contribution on this community:)